# Evaluating expressions involving roots of unity

Tags: group-theory, roots-of-unity

I'm trying to evaluate

$$\zeta_5^3+\zeta_5^2+1$$

I got a mess of roots but I think it should be something simple involving $\sqrt{5}$. Any help?

Comment: Since the two fifth roots are conjugate, their sum will be real and twice the cosine of 144 degrees.

Comment: Since $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4=0$ for $\zeta=\zeta_5$, you can also rewrite this in terms of $\zeta^2$ and $\zeta^4=\zeta^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\zeta^3+\zeta^2+1=-\zeta-\zeta^4=-\zeta-\zeta^{-1}=-\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}-i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)=$$
$$=-2\cos72^{\circ}=-2\cdot\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct about *something simple involving $\sqrt{5}$*, since
$$ G(\chi_5)= \zeta_5-\zeta_5^2-\zeta_5^3+\zeta_5^4\tag{A} $$
is a [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum), and $\left|G(\chi_5)\right|=\sqrt{5}$ simply follows by squaring. The real part of $G(\chi_5)$ is quite clearly positive, hence $G(\chi_5)=\sqrt{5}$. We also have
$$ \zeta_5+\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3+\zeta_5^4 = -1 \tag{B}$$
hence by considering the difference between $(B)$ and $(A)$ we have
$$ 2(\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3) = -1-\sqrt{5},\qquad \zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3+1=\color{red}{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}.\tag{C} $$